# opencart Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "str_replace

Tags: opencart-3

I was trying to change the layout of the side menu. So I went to theme editor of opencart admin backend and edit the header.twig file. Then my site immediately went down. I tried reset the file but no help. Below are some details.

Opencart version: 3.0.2.0
Template used: default template(It is Laparis)
File edited: header.twig(Already reset but no help)

Error message from log:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message
>   'Unknown "str_replace" function in
>   "__string_template__114ffe1f7b42f3814d23134616d33d0e68757819b2b243a229946d6b949a3d2d"
>   at line 18.' in
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:574
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(351):
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass('str_replace', 18) #1
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(144):
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNode('str_replace', 18) #2
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(84):
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression() #3
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(41):
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->getPrimary() #4
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(91):
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parseExpression() #5 /home/lbabatkcom/public in
>   /home/lbabatkcom/public_html/demo/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php
>   on line 574

I thought it might be the cache issue, so I cleared all cache. But still no luck.

Comment: Please set twig debug is true in  **/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php**
set 
**$options = array_merge(array(
            'debug' => true, (flase to true)
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            'base_template_class' => 'Twig_Template',
            'strict_variables' => false,
            'autoescape' => 'html',
            'cache' => false,
            'auto_reload' => null,
            'optimizations' => -1,
        ), $options);**

Comment: i did that, nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute PHP in a Twig file.

You can run PHP code in the controller then pass the result to the Twig file.